# Fix table and let text float around

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

For my thesis, I need to fix tables on certain pages such that any text before them continues after them. Text should break with hyphens.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blindmathtrue
\blindtext

{\centering \noindent\includegraphics[height=11cm]{example-image-b}}

\blindmathfalse
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

For instance, I want the picture to have on the bottom of page 1, and any text above should continue on page 2 without shifting the picture to page 2. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `{\centering` will not centre the image unless you have a paragraph end before the `}` but otherwise you have a non-floating image so it can only go on the first page if there is room, which there is not.

Comment: as far as I understand the question, you should use `\begin{figure}[b]\centering \includegraphics...`

Answer (score 3):

You need a floating figure, and let it float to the bottom of the pge:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!b]
\centering \includegraphics[height=11cm]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\blindmathtrue
\blindtext


\blindmathfalse
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: the image is too wide for the page but I assume that's just the example image

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks David, much appreciated!